# I have installed Blender on a different laptop and I wish to copy my settings, but can't find folder

Tags: config, files

I usually place "config, datafiles and scripts" into `Username/appdata/Roaming/Blender Foundation` but the `Blender Foundation` folder just doesn't exist.

I have a very specific user interface and hotkeys and I wish to use said preferences and config on this laptop. It's Windows 11 and no the folders are not hidden.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

See the docs: [Blender’s Directory Layout](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html)

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\

You can paste that into run menu ( <kbd>Winlogo</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd> ) to open in Windows. "%USERPROFILE%" determines current user.

The preferences do not exist until you start Blender for the first time after fresh installation. It's fine to just create the path and paste your folder there in that case as well and once you open Blender it will use that even if it's the first time it starts on that machine.

For your convenience:

`cmd /C md "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\"`

Will create the folder if you paste it into run menu.

Also if you use portable version it stores its settings locally wherever it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand the question, but I'll answer to the best of my abilities.

Try looking in your *Downloads* folder. It should be there with the date you installed it. You could also try searching `Blender` in your computer's search-bar, under *Apps* or *Documents*.

If you use a web browser like FireFox, you could click the *Downloads* drop-down, right-click on the Blender file, and hit *Show in Folder*. This should take you to your file's location.

Also, downloading Blender onto a different device than your current one won't save your preferences. You'll have to re-save them.